# Reuse node_module across different react apps

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have setup react using NodeJS according to [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm)

Since I am learning React, I have to create multiple small projects. I am using `create-react-app`. This is causing:

1. Delay in creation of the app (Even when we have node installed while creating a previous app(s).
2. Allocation of ~200 MB for node_modules folder

Is it possible to reuse the dependencies created for one project, to be used in another?

I have tried copying **node_modules** from earlier projects to this one but I get following error while executing `npm start`

```
> products@0.1.0 start /Users/Deven/playground/React/test
> react-scripts start

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:783
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/start'
```

in essence the softlinks to files are broken. Also copying node_modules is consuming space so I would like to reuse it.

Comment: It's not really a `create-react-app` issue. `npm` can be configured to work offline and use the cache only, but usually you do this via the command line. Since `create-react-app` is running it for you, then you have to configure it globally. https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#cache-min

Comment: usually, the recent version of npm's cache the downloaded package.. so running npm would not actually download the package from internet, instead it just fetches the meta data and checks to see if you have latest version in cache and does the installation. so give it a try and see

Comment: Rectangular :Thank you for the inputs. 
@Panther : Indeed.I turned off the internet and ran create-react-app. Though there were errors suggesting the cause as network, the functionality was not impacted. Thank you for inputs.
The problem though is, a new folder for the project is created having sub folder node_module that takes ~200MB. Is there a way I can link previous one to this project so I can save on memory. and if this can happen automatically for subsequent creation of app (not necessarily by create-react-app command)

Comment: I am able to get workaround which is via using subdirectories inside the 'main' react app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get workaround using node_modules in the main app and reusing the same by creating sub-directories for each app in main.  In the example I created app called mouseover

1. Create a **main** app using `create-react-app` command.

> `create-react-app main`

2. It will have node_modules, public and src folders. The `public` and the `src` folders are small in size and we can create these for individual apps.
3. For new app, create a folder for app inside src directory of main.

   > cd main/src/ 
   >   mkdir mouseover
4. Copy Sample `public` and `src` to the new folder.

> cp -r ../../sample/src ./mouseover/
>      `cp -r ../../sample/public ./mouseover/`

5. Modify App.js to import `App` from `src/App' from new app folder and return it (index.js of main to consume)

> `sed -i ''  's/import App1 from .*/import App1 from \".\/mouseover\/src\/App\"/g' App.js`

The App.js in main will look like following after importing App from new app and returning it.

```
import React from "react"

import "./App.css"
import App1 from "./mousehover/src/App"

function App() {
  return (
    <App1 />
  )
}

export default App
```